# Centos 7 GUI Freeze problem

Tags: centos, freeze, intel-graphics, graphic-card

I have installed CentOS 7 DVD ISO on my MSI GE70 Laptop that has geforce gtx 765m, when the GUI comes after 5 seconds screen freeze.

Is this an nvidia problem? How can I solve it?

I cannot disable my geforce video card from BIOS. So how can I use my default video or there is solution for that? Even if I use my default video card there will be a problem about watching videos on youtube, etc., because of lag issue.

Comment: Is the system up to date?  Are you using the open source nvidia drivers, or the 3rd-party ones?